# How has this search page been implemented (javascript, css, jquery?)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, search

http://designspiration.net - If you click on search at the top of the page, you are presented with a really cool minimal search form, But I cannot find out how they did it. Does anyone know/could anyone find out what was used? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's done with CSS and jQuery, pretty easy actually. 
I have created an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/VeRMW/) demonstrating how it could be done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $overlay = $('#overlay');
    $('#search').click(function(){
        if ( $overlay.is(':visible') ) {
            $overlay.fadeOut();
        } else {
            $overlay.fadeIn();
        }           
    });

    $('#close').click(function(){
        $overlay.fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Have a look here: [http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/VeRMW/](http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/VeRMW/show/)

The main functions are, [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Comment: The blink cursor, could be a background image. For example, a .gif image which fakes the blinking effect. And on `input:focus` you just set the `background-image` property to `none`

Answer (score 2):

It uses an overlay on the whole page and a big text field with no borders which search on enter and some suggestions

You could do it by jQuery & CSS

Comment: Thanks, do you know how the flashing cursor is achieved?

Comment: Just make the input field big lets say width:400px; height:90px; font-size:72px;

Comment: No, I meant the effect of the blinking line - otherwise the field is invisible.